# Pegar SQL antes do POST em um ZQuery

Tags: sql, post, delphi-7, zeos

Galera, alguém sabe como pegar o sql executado no POST de uma query em modo insert?
Por exemplo, tenho a tabela aluno com id e nome:

```
begin
    tblAluno.Insert;
    tblAlunoID.asInteger := 1;
    tblAlunoNome.asString := 'Carlos';
    //aqui
    tblAluno.Post;
end;
```

Justamente em "aqui" quero pegar o sql que é executado por baixo com o insert.
Perceba que se eu colocar: clipboard.asText := tblAluno.Sql.Text ele me retorna o sql  da query e não o que realmente foi executado no post.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode pegar sql do UpdateObject
ex.:

```
ZQuery.UpdateObject.InsertSQL;
ZQuery.UpdateObject.DeleteSQL;
ZQuery.UpdateObject.ModifySQL;
```

---

@jack, então você pode tentar da seguinte maneira:

```
var
   strLista: TStrings;
   idx: Integer;
begin
   strLista := nil;
   try
      strLista := TStringList.Create;
      strLista.Text := ZQuery.UpdateObject.InsertSQL.Text;
      strLista.Add('=======================================')
      for idx := 0 to ZQuery.Fields.Count - 1 do
      begin
         strLista.Add(ZQuery.Fields[idx].Name + ' = ' + ZQuery.Fields[idx].AsString);
      end;

      Clipboard.AsText := strLista.Text;
   finally
      if Assigned(strLista) then
         FreeAndNil(strLista);
   end;
end;
```

ele vai pegar o sql, e no final ele vai adicionar os parâmetros e seus respectivos valores, (deve ser colocado no before post da zquery)

Comment: Brother @dennis90, havia tentado isso: 
    ShowMessage(ZQuery1.UpdateObject.InsertSQL.Text);
    ShowMessage(ZQuery1.UpdateObject.SQL[ukInsert].Text);
1.UpdateObject.SQL[ukInsert].Text);
E ocorre erro de memória ao acessar a propriedade.

Comment: há algum componente definido na propriedade UpdateObject da zquery?

Comment: Na propriedade UpdateObject não há nenhum componente. Mas na propriedade UpdateMode está como: umUpdateChanged

Comment: Se eu colocar um objeto TZUpdateSQl na query dá certo, ele acessa a propriedade UpdateObject.InsertSQL, porém ele mostra ela com os parâmetros não preenchidos: update tabela set campo1 = :valor. Preciso acessar o sql sem o componente update e antes do post com os campos preenchidos.

Comment: Editei a mensagem, verifica o novo código adicionado.

Comment: beleza, não deixa de ser uma solução, mas imagine se vc tiver uma query com mais de 20 campos, vou precisar pegar o clipboard e substituir parâmetro por parâmetro no sql para ai sim executar no ibexpert até descobrir o erro. Sem falar que este código só funciona se a query estiver ligada a um componente ZUPdateSQL, caso o contrário ganharei uma exception.

Comment: Amigo, desculpa pela demora em responder, porém se você tiver algum erro na query e não tiver componentne UpdateSQL atribuido, este erro não será pelo SQL da query, tente reformular a pergunta com o erro que você está enfrentando que nós tentaremos ajudar.

Comment: Bem @dennis90,  eu não tenho erro, preciso apenas do sql de insert que é executado quando realizo o post como citei na pergunta lá em cima. E não tenho um componente updateSQL ligado a query.

Comment: Por isso o QueryTable padrão do Delphi é muito bom, pois ele monta as 4 queries para você. Pena que não tem esse no Zeos.

Answer (score 0):

Jack, eu recomendo que você não use `ZTable`, apenas em casos muito extremos. Jogue um `ZQuery` no `DataModule` e atribua à sua conexão. Depois jogue um `ZUpdateSQL` e atribua-o ao `ZQuery` na propriedade `UpdateSQL`. Em sua `ZQuery` modifique a propriedade SQL.Text para '`SELECT * FROM Tabela WHERE algumacoisa = algumacoisa;`'. Depois dê um duplo clique no `ZUpdateSQL` e uma janela se abrirá. Clique em '`Generate SQL`' e ele fará primorosamente os 3 códigos, para `DELETE`, `UPDATE` e `INSERT`. Você pode depois editá-los e melhorá-los da forma que desejar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Coloque `WHERE id = :id;` no final de UPDATE e DELETE se você usa esse tipo de campo para diferenciar cada registro e não acabar mexendo em outros registros.